# How to allow Javascript Methods to share a variable within an Object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, global-variables

I am just wondering if there is a way to have a global variable within an object. I need all the methods of a certain object to be able to share a variable instead of having the same variable rewritten in each method.

example:
This is what I am doing now..

```
    var myObject = {
          methodOne: function(){
            var myVariable = 'stuff';
            console.log(myVariable);
          },
         methodTwo: function(){
            var myVariable = 'stuff';
            console.log(myVariable);
          }
    }
```

This is what I want to do....

```
    var myObject = {
          var myVariable = 'stuff';
          methodOne: function(){
            console.log(myVariable);
          },
         methodTwo: function(){
            console.log(myVariable);
          }
    }
```

I think I might have some syntax wrong, but I have tried it different ways and the methods will not run. Surprisingly I have not been able to find a direct answer to this topic on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set `myVariable` as myObject's attribute, then you can use `this.myVariable` to access it in your functions.

```js
var myObject = {
      myVariable: 'stuff',
      methodOne: function(){
        // If you use myObject.xxx to call the function, then
        // `this` will be the reference of `myObject`, so you
        // can get `myVariable` by `this.myVariable`.
        console.log(this.myVariable);
      },
     methodTwo: function(){
        console.log(this.myVariable);
      }
}

myObject.methodOne();
myObject.methodTwo();
```

Or if you don't want `myVariable` be accessible to others:

```js
// Create a function that will return an Object, and execute it immediately.
// By this way, myVariable now is only visible to the 2 method in the return object
// as they're in the same function scope.
var myObject = (function() {
  var myVariable = 'stuff';
  
  return {
    methodOne: function(){
      console.log(myVariable);
    },
    methodTwo: function(){
      console.log(myVariable);
    }
  };
})();

console.log(myObject); // Only 2 methods in myObject
// But both still share the same var myVariable
myObject.methodOne();  
myObject.methodTwo();
```

Comment: Awesome I knew it was something as simple as that.  the 'this' keyword' was the problem in this situation.